# Python class basics functions not working

Tags: python, class, oop

Why the binary tree is not getting inverted in this class?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right= None
        self.data = data
    def show_tree (self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.show_tree()
        print(self.data)
        if self.right:      
            self.right.show_tree()
class Operation:
    def invertTree(self,root):
        if root:
            root.left, root.right==root.right, root.left
            self.invertTree(root.left)
            self.invertTree(root.right)
        return root 



root = Node(10)
b=Node(15)
c=Node(19)
d=Node(5)
e=Node(59)
d.left=e
d.right=c
root.left=b
root.right=d

root.show_tree()


oper=Operation()
inver =oper.invertTree(root)
inver.show_tree()
```

The other class is returning the inverted root so finally it should return the inverted root to inver but when I display it, it shows same tree

Answer (score 1):

`root.left, root.right==root.right, root.left` compares the values and returns a boolean, if you want to assign you need to use a single `=` operator

Comment: i feel so dumb, thank

Comment: For next time, I suggest you use a debugger or add prints to understand what goes wrong. It'll be faster and give you better experience. Pycharm has a great debugger for python

Comment: @SurDin You should vote to close such question as typo rather than answering them.

Comment: I disagree. They genuinely didn't find the problem, the code is relatively concise. I would rather help. There are many other questions that are worth closing